# How do I locate the source_file path?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and just started troubleshooting a project that another developer created.  The first line of his script refers to the source_file.

I am trying to figure out how to find the entire path, I need to look at the actual .csv file in this case and I am not sure where to look.

Here is a snip of the code.

```
# for local environment only, read the source file 
source_file = open("Python/resource/12345.csv", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
source_data = source_file.read()
source_file.close()
import json
```

We tried using putty to the linux dev servers and have not been able to locate the file.

Comment: There's no specific place to look. Python looks in the `Python/resouce` subdirectory of your working directory. So whoever wrote this assumed that the user would be in the appropriate parent directory.

Comment: Or you're expected to create the source file for your actual needs. You have to create the `Python/resource` subdirectory, and put the file there.

Answer (score 0):

Does that program run as it should in the local environment?

The folder it searches for the file to open is `$(pwd)/Python/resource/` (pwd = your current folder, assuming you're launching the script from the same directory)

Due to the `r` flag, the file won't be automatically created by Python if it doesn't exist. Maybe you have to create the folder `Python/resource/` and then the `12345.csv` file?

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file from `Python/resource/12345.csv` you're really opening a  file from the path relative to the current directory. If you want to find the "whole path" you could just add the `CWD` to the file location.

```py
import os

filepath = "/Python/resource/12345.csv"

print(os.getcwd().replace("\\", "/") + filepath)

# Prints C:/path/Python/resource/12345.csv
```